# POO com PHP $_POST

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, post

Como deve ser feito para que um valor da super global $_POST entre em uma classe.

Já tentei várias maneiras , mas sem sucesso.  Esse valor será tratado dentro da classe.

Comment: Coloca o código que já tem

Comment: Pelo pouco que deu pra entender da pergunta, você quer pegar um dado passado via post, e construir um objeto com ele? Utilizando métodos e/ou funções da classe, seria isso?

Comment: Naverdade não. Naverdade fazer ele entrar na classe. Já consegui fazer isso passando por parametro e mostrar. Porém ao aplicar PagSeguroTransactionSearchService::searchByCode($credentials, $transaction_code); ($transition_code deve vir pelo POST ) não funciona. Mas se eu setar dentro da classe, aí sim funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Resgate o parâmetro recebido pelo método post

```
$transaction_code = $_POST['transaction_code'];
```

Feito isso, passe para o parâmetro do método da classe:

```
PagSeguroTransactionSearchService::searchByCode($credentials, $transaction_code);
```

Exemplo completo

```
<?php
$transaction_code = $_POST['transaction_code'];
PagSeguroTransactionSearchService::searchByCode($credentials,$transaction_code);
```

Comment: esse trecho "Exemplo completo" é só pra encher linguiça, pra dizer que tem conteúdo na resposta.. rsrs

Comment: esse é daquele tipo de tópico "caixinha de surpresas".. rsrs a cada post uma surpresa que complementa a pergunta.. Veja bem, se cai no catch, deve aparecer mensagem de erro. Há alguma mensagem de erro? Qual ?  E ... assim, seria melhor ter colocado o código na sua pergunta e não na minha resposta.. ficou bem estranho.

Comment: Realmente é um post "caixinha de surpresas" o autor pergunta sobre PDO e depois ele falou que é sobre o PagSeguro, ou seja a pergunta está mal formulada rs. Mas acredito que a sua resposta ajude a esta pergunta não ser fechada, só recomendo você editar a pergunta, para que a sua resposta não fique parecendo "invalida". (acredito que você já tenha poder de edição)